# InstanceProfile is required for creating cluster

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-iam, amazon-emr

I was trying to run Elastic MapReduce from Eclipse but couldn't do so.

My code is as below:

```
public class RunEMR {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("xxxx","xxxx");
            AmazonElasticMapReduceClient emr = new AmazonElasticMapReduceClient(credentials);

            StepFactory stepFactory = new StepFactory();

            StepConfig enableDebugging = new StepConfig()
                .withName("Enable Debugging")
                .withActionOnFailure("TERMINATE_JOB_FLOW")
                .withHadoopJarStep(stepFactory.newEnableDebuggingStep());

            StepConfig installHive = new StepConfig()
                .withName("Install Hive")
                .withActionOnFailure("TERMINATE_JOB_FLOW")
                .withHadoopJarStep(stepFactory.newInstallHiveStep());

            StepConfig hiveScript = new StepConfig().withName("Hive Script")
                .withActionOnFailure("TERMINATE_JOB_FLOW")
                .withHadoopJarStep(stepFactory.newRunHiveScriptStep("s3://mywordcountbuckett/binary/WordCount.jar"));

            RunJobFlowRequest request = new RunJobFlowRequest()
                .withName("Hive Interactive")
                .withSteps(enableDebugging, installHive)
                .withLogUri("s3://mywordcountbuckett/")
                .withInstances(new JobFlowInstancesConfig()
                    .withEc2KeyName("xxxx")
                    .withHadoopVersion("0.20")
                    .withInstanceCount(3)
                    .withKeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps(true)
                    .withMasterInstanceType("m1.small")
                    .withSlaveInstanceType("m1.small"));

            RunJobFlowResult result = emr.runJobFlow(request);



    }

}
```

The error that I got was :

```
Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: InstanceProfile is required for creating cluster. (Service: AmazonElasticMapReduce; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: 7a96ee32-9744-11e5-947d-65ca8f7db0a5
```

I have tried for couple of hours but unable to fix it. Does anyone knows how ?

Answer (score 4):

I got same exception `InstanceProfile is required for creating cluster`.

Had to set service-role, and job-flow-role like below

```
aRunJobFlowRequest.setServiceRole("EMR_DefaultRole")
aRunJobFlowRequest.setJobFlowRole("EMR_EC2_DefaultRole")
```

After that I was OK.

---

[AWS Document for EMR IAM Roles](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-iam-roles.html) said

> AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) roles provide a way for IAM users or AWS services to have certain specified permissions and access to resources. For example, this may allow users to access resources or other services to act on your behalf. You must specify two IAM roles for a cluster: a role for the Amazon EMR service (service role), and a role for the EC2 instances (instance profile) that Amazon EMR manages.

So word `InstanceProfile` in exception message might mean `a role for the EC2 instances (instance profile)` in the doc, but I got pass that exception after specifying `JobFlowRole`. little weird.

Comment: do you mind posting your full source code to enable EMR cluster ?

Comment: i have an error "m3.xlarge instance type is not supported with AMI version 1.0.0"

Answer (score 1):

For an ec2 role (here jobflowrole), an instance profile with the same nameis created internally. Hence it uses these names interchangeably. 
If you creating an emr cluster from scratch using boto3, you should also create emr service role, one ec2jobflow role , one instance profile linked to ec2jobflow role.
[AWS doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-iam-roles.html)
[image: referencing AWs documentation]

Comment: Thank you for this! I was trying to figure out the link between the instance profile and the role, and was having trouble due to the setup being done with terraform and not the console.

Answer (score 0):

The version you are trying to use is deprecated and IAM roles are required. Follow the example as given in the documentation http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/ManagementGuide/calling-emr-with-java-sdk.html.

Comment: I have seen the documentation. What should I replace "myApp" with in .withApplications(myApp) ?